# How to activate the "Invisible Mode"?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

In forums you have the option of browsing the site "invisibly" i.e without letting others know that you are online.

Even information like when you last logged in is  kept hidden from others once you have activated the "Invisible Mode" .

I have searched for this feature in the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab but could not find any.

So ,is this feature not available on this site?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this site has such a feature, although I'm not sure what what benefit that feature would have on a site like this.  But in any case you can achieve much the same effect by browsing while not signed in.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes not much difference it will make except for if implemented and activated users last log in info will not be shown viz- ,"the user xyz was active(last seen) n secs/mins ago" ,this info will not be shown in his profile.Nothing else.Anyways i was just curious to know.. :)

Comment: @Rickross If you don't want to be tracked, try Google Chrome incognito mode or Firefox private browsing without logging into Hinduism.SE.

Comment: Similar [FR](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260307/260388) is pending.